# How to build a parent key based on a sub-string of another value using jq?

Tags: json, key, jq

I'm re-shaping a JSON file which base content is the output of an AWS API call. From the raw output, I'm currently extracting the fields that I'm interested in the format I want except for a small detail that motivated this question.

Specifically, my input comes from the output of `aws rds describe-db-instances` command and contains the info of multiple RDS instances. Taking an example with 2 instances, this is how it looks:

```
{
"DBInstances": [
    {
        "DBInstanceIdentifier": "db1-name",
        "DBInstanceClass": "db.m5.xlarge",
        "Engine": "oracle-ee",
        "DBInstanceStatus": "available",
        "MasterUsername": "user",
        "DBName": "RANDOM",
        "Endpoint": {
            "Address": "some-endpoint.rds.amazonaws.com",
            "Port": 5698,
            "HostedZoneId": "GHDSFHFSDHSDH"
        },
        "AllocatedStorage": 4000,
        "InstanceCreateTime": "2018-07-23T23:21:42.361000+00:00",
        "PreferredBackupWindow": "09:30-07:00",
        "BackupRetentionPeriod": 14,
        "DBSecurityGroups": [],
        "VpcSecurityGroups": [
            {
                "VpcSecurityGroupId": "sg-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "Status": "active"
            },
            {
                "VpcSecurityGroupId": "sg-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "Status": "active"
            }
        ],
        "DBParameterGroups": [
            {
                "DBParameterGroupName": "DB1-parameter",
                "ParameterApplyStatus": "in-sync"
            }
        ],
        "AvailabilityZone": "ZONE1",
        "DBSubnetGroup": {
            "DBSubnetGroupName": "dbsubnetgroup-1",
            "DBSubnetGroupDescription": "dbsubnetgroup-1",
            "VpcId": "vpc-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "SubnetGroupStatus": "Complete",
            "Subnets": [
                {
                    "SubnetIdentifier": "subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    "SubnetAvailabilityZone": {
                        "Name": "az1"
                    },
                    "SubnetStatus": "Active"
                },
                {
                    "SubnetIdentifier": "subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    "SubnetAvailabilityZone": {
                        "Name": "az2"
                    },
                    "SubnetStatus": "Active"
                }
            ]
        },
        "PreferredMaintenanceWindow": "sat:07:00-sat:07:30",
        "PendingModifiedValues": {},
        "LatestRestorableTime": "2020-03-27T18:54:25+00:00",
        "MultiAZ": false,
        "EngineVersion": "X.X.X",
        "AutoMinorVersionUpgrade": false,
        "ReadReplicaDBInstanceIdentifiers": [],
        "LicenseModel": "bring-your-own-license",
        "Iops": 5000,
        "OptionGroupMemberships": [
            {
                "OptionGroupName": "optiongroupName",
                "Status": "in-sync"
            }
        ],
        "CharacterSetName": "WE8ISO8859P15",
        "PubliclyAccessible": false,
        "StorageType": "io1",
        "DbInstancePort": 0,
        "StorageEncrypted": true,
        "KmsKeyId": "someKey",
        "DbiResourceId": "db-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "CACertificateIdentifier": "rds-ca-2019",
        "DomainMemberships": [],
        "CopyTagsToSnapshot": true,
        "MonitoringInterval": 0,
        "DBInstanceArn": "someARN",
        "IAMDatabaseAuthenticationEnabled": false,
        "PerformanceInsightsEnabled": false,
        "DeletionProtection": false,
        "AssociatedRoles": []
    },
    {
        "DBInstanceIdentifier": "db2-name",
        "DBInstanceClass": "db.m5.large",
        "Engine": "oracle-ee",
        "DBInstanceStatus": "available",
        "MasterUsername": "user2",
        "DBName": "XXXX",
        "Endpoint": {
            "Address": "endpoint2.rds.amazonaws.com",
            "Port": 8974,
            "HostedZoneId": "FASDFDS54FSA"
        },
        "AllocatedStorage": 100,
        "InstanceCreateTime": "2020-04-23T21:38:53.023000+00:00",
        "PreferredBackupWindow": "01:00-05:30",
        "BackupRetentionPeriod": 35,
        "DBSecurityGroups": [],
        "VpcSecurityGroups": [
            {
                "VpcSecurityGroupId": "sg-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "Status": "active"
            }
        ],
        "DBParameterGroups": [
            {
                "DBParameterGroupName": "default",
                "ParameterApplyStatus": "in-sync"
            }
        ],
        "AvailabilityZone": "AZ-2",
        "DBSubnetGroup": {
            "DBSubnetGroupName": "subnet-group",
            "DBSubnetGroupDescription": "",
            "VpcId": "vpc-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "SubnetGroupStatus": "Complete",
            "Subnets": [
                {
                    "SubnetIdentifier": "subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    "SubnetAvailabilityZone": {
                        "Name": "AZ-1"
                    },
                    "SubnetStatus": "Active"
                },
                {
                    "SubnetIdentifier": "subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    "SubnetAvailabilityZone": {
                        "Name": "AZ-2"
                    },
                    "SubnetStatus": "Active"
                },
                {
                    "SubnetIdentifier": "subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    "SubnetAvailabilityZone": {
                        "Name": "AZ-3"
                    },
                    "SubnetStatus": "Active"
                }
            ]
        },
        "PreferredMaintenanceWindow": "sun:08:39-sun:09:09",
        "PendingModifiedValues": {},
        "LatestRestorableTime": "2020-07-27T18:53:18+00:00",
        "MultiAZ": false,
        "EngineVersion": "X.X.X",
        "AutoMinorVersionUpgrade": false,
        "ReadReplicaDBInstanceIdentifiers": [],
        "LicenseModel": "bring-your-own-license",
        "Iops": 2000,
        "OptionGroupMemberships": [
            {
                "OptionGroupName": "optiongroup-name",
                "Status": "in-sync"
            }
        ],
        "CharacterSetName": "AL32UTF8",
        "PubliclyAccessible": false,
        "StorageType": "io1",
        "DbInstancePort": 0,
        "StorageEncrypted": true,
        "KmsKeyId": "someARN",
        "DbiResourceId": "db-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "CACertificateIdentifier": "rds-ca-2019",
        "DomainMemberships": [],
        "CopyTagsToSnapshot": false,
        "MonitoringInterval": 0,
        "DBInstanceArn": "someARN",
        "IAMDatabaseAuthenticationEnabled": false,
        "PerformanceInsightsEnabled": false,
        "DeletionProtection": false,
        "AssociatedRoles": []
    }
]
```

}

This is my current output:

```
[
  {
    "DBInstancePrefix": {
      "DBInstanceClass": "db.m5.xlarge",
      "DBInstanceIdentifier": "db1-name",
      "DBName": "RANDOM",
      "DBParameterGroupName": "DB1-parameter",
      "DBSubnetGroupName": "dbsubnetgroup-1",
      "KmsKeyId": "someKey",
      "OptionGroupName": "optiongroupName",
      "VpcSecurityGroupIds": [
        "sg-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "sg-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "DBInstancePrefix": {
      "DBInstanceClass": "db.m5.large",
      "DBInstanceIdentifier": "db2-name",
      "DBName": "XXXX",
      "DBParameterGroupName": "default",
      "DBSubnetGroupName": "subnet-group",
      "KmsKeyId": "someARN",
      "OptionGroupName": "optiongroup-name",
      "VpcSecurityGroupIds": [
        "sg-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

This is my current JQ filter:

```
. | [.[] | map(.) | .[] | {DBInstancePrefix: {DBInstanceClass: .DBInstanceClass, DBInstanceIdentifier: .DBInstanceIdentifier, DBName: .DBName, DBParameterGroupName:.DBParameterGroups[].DBParameterGroupName, DBSubnetGroupName: .DBSubnetGroup.DBSubnetGroupName, KmsKeyId:.KmsKeyId, OptionGroupName: .OptionGroupMemberships[].OptionGroupName, VpcSecurityGroupIds: [.VpcSecurityGroups | .[] | .VpcSecurityGroupId] }}]
```

You can verify it on this snippet on [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/zQqEfm9yN_).

**What I need is to turn the parent key "DBInstancePrefix" dynamic based on a substring from "DBInstanceIdentifier" key**. So for the example names I wrote would be:

> "db1-name" >>> "db1"

> "db2-name" >>> "db2"

So, my desired output would be:

```
[
  {
    "db1": {
      "DBInstanceClass": "db.m5.xlarge",
      "DBInstanceIdentifier": "db1-name",
      "DBName": "RANDOM",
      "DBParameterGroupName": "DB1-parameter",
      "DBSubnetGroupName": "dbsubnetgroup-1",
      "KmsKeyId": "someKey",
      "OptionGroupName": "optiongroupName",
      "VpcSecurityGroupIds": [
        "sg-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "sg-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "db2": {
      "DBInstanceClass": "db.m5.large",
      "DBInstanceIdentifier": "db2-name",
      "DBName": "XXXX",
      "DBParameterGroupName": "default",
      "DBSubnetGroupName": "subnet-group",
      "KmsKeyId": "someARN",
      "OptionGroupName": "optiongroup-name",
      "VpcSecurityGroupIds": [
        "sg-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks for reading.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To manipulate the object key-name as you desire, you can apply the filter operation inside `(..)`. Any operation done inside it, the result is preserved "literally".

Your case demands the `DBInstanceIdentifier` to be split by `-` and using the first element in the resultant array.

With that and few other trivial modifications, you need

```
.DBInstances |
map
(
  {
    ( .DBInstanceIdentifier | split("-")[0] ): {
         DBInstanceClass,
         DBInstanceIdentifier,
         DBName,
         DBParameterGroupName:.DBParameterGroups[].DBParameterGroupName,
         DBSubnetGroupName: .DBSubnetGroup.DBSubnetGroupName,
         KmsKeyId,
         OptionGroupName: .OptionGroupMemberships[].OptionGroupName,
         VpcSecurityGroupIds: [.VpcSecurityGroups[] | .VpcSecurityGroupId ]
      }
  }
)
```

<sup>[jqplay - Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/BWJ47aO63X)</sup>

Comment: That was much more simpler that what I did. I have a lot to learn about jq. Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

I took the long path and since I couldn't resolve it on the same filter I did another one that takes the output of the first one and thus achieved the desired result. But it is awful compared with the answer selected as the solution.

Based on [Inian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5291015/inian) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63136850/7820212), I did a small modification since my real *DBInstanceIdentifier* values have the following format:
`<name>-db-<environment>` and I need *DBInstancePrefix* becomes `<name>-db`.

So, my final filter is:

```
.DBInstances |
map
(      
  {        
    ( .DBInstanceIdentifier|split("-")[0:2] | join("-") ): {
      DBInstanceClass,
      DBInstanceIdentifier,
      DBName,
      DBParameterGroupName:.DBParameterGroups[].DBParameterGroupName,
      DBSubnetGroupName: .DBSubnetGroup.DBSubnetGroupName,
      KmsKeyId,
      OptionGroupName: .OptionGroupMemberships[].OptionGroupName,
      VpcSecurityGroupIds: [.VpcSecurityGroups[] | .VpcSecurityGroupId ]        
      }     
  } 
)
```